# Can't ping my ubuntu 18.04 from Windows machines using FQDN

Tags: networking, 18.04, windows, dns, ping

I have been trying to connect an Ubuntu 18.04 system to a windows network at work.

Once installed, I have tried pinging the Ubuntu machine from a Windows machine and vice versa.

The windows machine is found and pings like clockwork.

When I try pinging the Ubuntu machine however, the FQDN method doesn't work.

I can ping the Ubuntu system by IP and hostname.

My **/etc/hosts** reads:

```
127.0.0.1    localhost
127.0.1.1    pagemattermost.hevs.ch s4bsu-server
153.109.5.99    pagemattermost.hevs.ch s4bsu-server   

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Output of various commands on my Ubuntu machine:

```
hostname: s4bsu-server
hostname -d:hevs.ch
hostname -f:pagemattermost.hevs.ch
```

My **ifconfig** output:

```
eno1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 153.109.5.99  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 153.109.5.255
        inet6 fe80::9354:37ce:e64c:aa94  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 98:90:96:c6:ba:18  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 28555  bytes 14650682 (14.6 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 17685  bytes 2766305 (2.7 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 20  memory 0xf7c00000-f7c20000  

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 9439  bytes 1727354 (1.7 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 9439  bytes 1727354 (1.7 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

The **Windows system IP config**:

```
Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : hevs.ch
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::a483:ab48:1ab0:ce8e%11
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 153.109.5.98
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 153.109.5.1
```

my **/etc/resolv.conf** output:

```
# Generated by NetworkManager
search hevs.ch
nameserver 153.109.6.36
nameserver 153.109.64.6
```

my **nslookup s4bsu-server** output:

```
;; Got SERVFAIL reply from 153.109.6.36, trying next server
Server:        153.109.64.6
Address:    153.109.64.6#53

** server can't find s4su-server: SERVFAIL
```

When I ping s4bsu-server and/or the IP, I get:

```
Pinging 153.109.5.99 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 153.109.5.99: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=64
Reply from 153.109.5.99: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 153.109.5.99: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 153.109.5.99: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64

Ping statistics for 153.109.5.99:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 2ms, Average = 1ms
```

I don't know why I can't ping and/or call the FQDN name.

I am also able to ssh to the ubuntu machine from the windows systems using the IP and hostname.

Maybe, I haven't understood FQDN properly or it is just a case of some stupidity that I have done or some silly issue with DNS in 18.04, but it has been a long day and I can't seem to figure it out. I have never had this issue in previous LTS versions with Gnome.

All help and suggestions would be much appreciated.

I can try furnish you with any and all additional information to help solve this issue.

Comment: Have you configured the domain at your DNS provider?

Comment: @colbycdev this is the only thing I had left to check, I couldn't reach the people at the DNS provider today.. maybe it is just that simple.. I was just covering all my bases in case it was a case of my incompetence.. ☺️

Comment: well check that first